# Is there a way to highlight (in bold) the name of bar in a bar chart in Plotly for Python?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am plotting a bar chart in Python using the Plotly library using a Jupyter notebook. I want to highlight the name of one of the bars (ideally in bold) to draw readers' attention to it and how it compares to other bars.

Here is a minimal, reproducible example of the type of graph I want to plot.

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode (connected = True)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'number']).set_index('name')

df.at['Alpha', 'number'] = 2
df.at['Beta', 'number'] = 3
df.at['Gamma', 'number'] = 5

trace = go.Bar(x=df.index, y=df['number'])

layout = go.Layout(
    title='Graph title.',
    yaxis=dict(title='Number'))

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)

iplot(fig)
```

The expected outcome is exactly the same graph I have now, but one of the names of the bar (for example `Gamma`) would be written in bold letters (or highlighted some other way).

[image: A simple bar chart]

Comment: There’s no way to change the formatting on certain tick labels unfortunately but you could consider adding an outline to a bar or a special text annotation within it or something like that

Answer (score 0):

So, after asking the question, I found a colleague who knew how to do it.

Since Plotly uses markdown language for text strings, it is enough to call each row in the dataframe that we want to highlight including the bold symbols `<b> </b>`.

```
df.at['Alpha', 'number'] = 2
df.at['Beta', 'number'] = 3
df.at['<b>Gamma</b>', 'number'] = 5
```